# Редактировать плагин Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Доброго времени суток.
Есть плагин для скрытия приватного контента - User Access Manager Private Extension.
Когда на сайте он скрывает нужный контент то пишет "Protected content."
Собственно говоря, хочу сменить текст плагина на свой!
Как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста!
Пытался через админ панель сайта сделать - не получилось.

Comment: как бы сделал я: нашёл папку этого плагина, и рекурсивно ( по всем файлам) задал поиск этого выражения "Protected content."  - думаю дальше поймёте что сделать... (правильный путь) или (если это возможно) дописать\создать файл с русской локализацией плагина, предложить разработчику)

Comment: Там текст сообщений в html виде записывается в таблицу опций. Либо в таблице опций текст поменяйте, либо в файле UserAccessManagerPrivateExtension.php до активации плагина.

Comment: Ребят, спасибо большое за советы. То есть все изменения надо вносить непосредственно в файлы плагина и до активации?

Comment: @Валентин , (у меня нет этого плагина), ... редактирование файлов возможно и в процессе работы плагина, как исключение могу предположить хэшерирование сообщения или какая-нибудь паранойя разработчика

Comment: @Shilgen, не сработало. Просто поменял текст, и плагин перестал работать. Фатальная ошибка. Менял текст в самом файле

Comment: @Валентин значит мои предположения оказались правдой и действительно Visman прав, до активации плагина ( хотя такое первый раз вижу, век живи век учись)

Comment: @Shilgen, я сделал и так и сяк, один и тот же текст выдает!!! Там плагин то на 2 строчки кода...

Comment: @Валентин текст этот в функции активации плагина, значит полюбому до этого его надо поменять... public function activate()
 {
  ....
  if (!get_option('uampe_private_text'))
   add_option('uampe_private_text', '<span id="uampe_private">Protected content.</span>', '', 'yes');....

Comment: @Shilgen, да, я нашел этот текст, спасибо конечно. Вот отредактировал я его, залил на хост снова. Активировал плагин, и выдает тот же текст Protected content

Comment: @Валентин, откройте в phpmyadmin (или какой инструмент у вас есть на хостинге для работы с БД напрямую) и в таблице опций wordpress отредактируйте содержимое текста для опции `uampe_private_text`.

Comment: объяснение ( больше для себя): плагин во время первой активации записал в БД значение опций, и поэтому и выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @Shilgen Пожалуйста, оформите ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

*@Visman  - спасибо за конструктивные комментарии,*

**Решение вопроса:**

1. При уже активированном и установленном плагине, любым удобным вам способом в таблице  wp_options в базе данных обновите (update) содержимое текста для опции uampe_private_text
2. Перед первой установкой: в файле UserAccessManagerPrivateExtension.php в строке поставить необходимый текст: `add_option('uampe_private_text', '<span id="uampe_private">Protected content.</span>', '', 'yes');`

**Объяснение:**

Плагин во время первой активации записал в БД значение опций (add_option), и поэтому и выдаёт ошибку, при деактивации плагина ничего не происходит, потому как в коде плагина содержимое функции function deactivate() закомментировано и поэтому "горячее редактирование" файлов и повторная активация  не будут давать ожидаемого результата.